# How to handle @types/any when it is only a stub types definition correctly?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

Say, I want to use [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) in my typescript project. Usually, I grab the typings of such a library by installing it's type definitions:

```
npm install @types/date-fns --save-dev
```

But sometimes, ony stubs are available. In the case of date-fsn it says `date-fns provides its own type definitions, so you don't need @types/date-fns installed!`

However, how do I integrate those typing files then into my project? Do I really need to put all those `*.d.ts` files into the `files` section of my `tscofig.json` or is there a better approach?

Comment: As it says `date-fns provides its own type definitions, so you don't need @types/date-fns installed!` You do not need to install or do anything other than install the package

Comment: If this is true, the module `devextreme` seems to be broken, because I had to explicitly add it's typings to my `tsconfg`. Otherwise it'd throw me `Cannot find namespace 'DevExpress'` when building the project using webpack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, how do I integrate those typing files then into my project?

When the project ships with type definitions *you don't need to install `@types`*. The project should work out of the box with TypeScript.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The module https://www.npmjs.com/package/devextreme then seems to be broken, because its typings need to explicitly be added to the `tsconfig` `files` section.

Answer (score 0):

**As a workaround:** `declare let DevExpress: any;`

Comment: I have removed all your NAA wording as answers is not the place for questions. This "workaround" however may not be enough to stop this post from being removed. You may need to expand on that.